# No error message from Validator in spring-data-rest

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-rest

Following the documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#validation I set up a very simple Validator for a spring-data-rest repository invocation:

```
public class DealValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return Deal.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
        errors.reject("deal.error", "No deal");
    }
}
```

And this is the configuration

```
@Override
protected void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener validatingListener) {
    validatingListener.addValidator("beforeCreate", new DealValidator());
}

@Configuration
static class I18nConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setBasename("classpath:messages");
        return source;
    }
}
```

The configuration seems to be alright, the validator is called correctly, the http-request yields an error response, but no error text is returned, neither from the messages.properties nor the default text. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across the same issue. Only validation errors that reference a field are serialized by spring-data-rest.

So you could use `rejectValue(String field, String errorCode, String defaultMessage)` instead of `reject`

See `org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.RepositoryConstraintViolationExceptionMessage` for implementation details. The implementation just processes `org.springframework.validation.Errors#getFieldErrors()`.

Comment: Yep, rejectValue brings the message. Thanks! I'll try to open a bug report.